# how to navigate in a list of items in angular, like, slecting and expanding and collapsing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of items, say topics, which I want to select, deselect, expand, and collapse. I have been searching and reading angular but the topic is not very well explained anywhere.

I know the viewContainerRef or elementRef can be a help here, along with viewchildern directive.
but still can't figure out how to do that.

anyhelp or link to some good reading material will be appreciated.

the belwo is the code I tried so far.

```
<ul #topicContent>
   
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroArray;let i=index;" >
    <li (click)="Expanded=Expanded==i?-1:i;  createComponent()"    appTopicexpand>
        Topic {{i}}
        <ul [hidden]="Expanded!=i?true:null" >
          <app-topiccontent></app-topiccontent>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </div>
    
</ul>
```

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { InmemorydataService } from '../inmemorydata.service';
import { TopiccontentComponent } from '../topiccontent/topiccontent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topicsmenu',
  templateUrl: './topicsmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topicsmenu.component.scss'],
})
export class TopicsmenuComponent {
  @ViewChildren ('topicContent') container !: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>; 

  heroArray=[];
  Expanded:number=-1;
  constructor(private dataService: InmemorydataService, private myref: ElementRef,private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef){}  
  ngOnInit(){
     this.dataService.createDb().subscribe(hero =>{
    
    console.log("hi");
  
    hero.forEach( (value : any) => {
      this.heroArray=hero;
    }); 
   })
  }
 
 createComponent(){
  console.log(this.viewContainerRef);
  
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess that you are looking for something like an Accordion component. If you are allowed to use a component library, or using one already you could check for an implementation of this type of component. For example, with Angular Material you already have an implementation for this. Check this [link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/accordion/overview). Also, you can implement an Accordion component by yourself if you can't or wish to use a component library. Let me know if you need some help with this.

Comment: of course, this is what I want. I am in learning phase, so I want to learn how it works.
library comes later and somehow I know there is a solution in Material but I don't want that, yet.

Comment: very simple functionality to implement, but I have no clue how to approach it in angular.